# How do I program Open GL without only Coordinate Geometry

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm starting to teach myself Open GL. I'm learning it for a pretty large iOS project. From what I can see so far, the way I'd program the graphics in my app is just a ton of coordinate geometry and meticulously typing out numbers. I'd like to use a graphics generator such as Blender to make some of these images. Can I use Blender for something like this in order to minimize the amount of annoying math necessary or am I restricted to vaguely picturing something in my mind and hoping I'm good enough at math to draw it? If it's the ladder, what other alternatives to Open GL can I find that would work for iOS?

Comment: Even with imported geometry data the will be math involved.

Comment: I'm well aware. I want to minimize the math involved as much as possible though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a tool like Blender to create your models and then write code to load them in OpenGL. [Here's some sample code](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Load_OBJ) and it even uses Blender. This was the first thing that came up when I did a web search for "loading obj files in OpenGL".